# How can I reset a flag to false, in just one statement, only if it is true & if its already true just ignore it?

Tags: php, logic

How can I reset a flag to false, in just one statement, only if it is true & if its already true just ignore it? I would also like to do opposite to this. Here is a situation, I want to ban a user only if he/she is active, if he/she is already banned I dont want to do anything. I also want to unban the user if he/she is banned but don't want to do anything if he/she is already active. Can this be clubbed in just one statement?

Comment: Please rephrase your question and give examples. "Reset only if it is true, and if it is true ignore" doesn't make any sense.

Comment: "How can I reset a flag to false, only if it is true & if its already true just ignore it?" What do you want to do, either you can ignore it, or you can set it to false, but those are opposites, you can't do both.

Comment: how would you write it in more than one statement or pseudocode?

Comment: What's wrong with just setting or resetting it explicitly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this has to be two statements (one to set a user to banned, the other to set the user to unbanned), but it does not have to be complicated.

Assuming that you have a flag "$banned", you would simply set that to `true` if you wanted the user banned, and `false` if the user is not supposed to be banned. It does not matter what that user was before -- simply continue on your way, everything should work itself out nicely.

With SQL, you might have a `BANNED` column. `UPDATE` won't care if the value is staying the same, so just run the update:

```
-- this will set BANNED to false. Use 1 to set it to true
UPDATE my_table SET BANNED = 0 WHERE ID = <your id>
```

All of that said, you may want to force the user to log out and log back in after they have been banned, but that is a matter for another question.

Comment: Cwallenpoole I was wondering if there exists a magical operator that can do some thing like this magical_operator(input, desired_boolean_ouput), so if magical_operator(true, true) I get true and for so if magical_operator(true, false) I get false, not sure if I am confused or something, though thanks for pointing out the SQL thing, I completely forgot about it

Comment: @Kumar, isn't the magical operator you're talking about `=` ??

Comment: I was talking abut some thing like this `update users set banned = !banned where user_id=myuser_id` this will work for me all the times at SQL level as it will reset the banned flag, @nickf, what I was talking about is negation not assignment :-)

Answer (score 0):

This sort of query might help you out a bit:

```
UPDATE `my_table` SET banned=(NOT banned) WHERE id = "<your id>"
```